# WP-плагин "хлебных крошек" Breadcrumb NavXT создает ненужный подраздел из get-запроса

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

Использую на сайте плагин "хлебных крошек" Breadcrumb NavXT.

В разделе "Новости" реализован ajax-фильтр: при переходе по ссылке вида `mysite.ru/news/?country=turkey` на странице остаются только новости про Турцию. При этом в "хлебных крошках" путь указан до основного раздела:

**Главная | Новости**

Появилась задача сделать полностью аналогичный раздел "События", только ajax-фильтр не по странам, а по годам. Полная копия новостей, настройки в Breadcrumb NavXT идентичные. Но при переходе по ссылке вида `mysite.ru/events/?years=2023` получаю в "хлебных крошках":

**Главная | События | 2023**

То есть происходит как бы переход в ненужный подраздел, чего по идее быть не должно (во всяком случае с новостями такого нет).

Почему абсолютно идентичные по реализации разделы по-разному обрабатываются плагином?

Каким образом плагин из get-параметра формирует подраздел, и как на это влиять?

Можно ли как-то исключить определённую таксономию (в данном случае "годы") из "Хлебных крошек"? /в настройках Breadcrumb NavXT не нашёл/